# Using Microsoft logging extensions with typed loggers when objects are instantiated in code?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Learning how to work with Microsoft logging extensions, DI and Serilog. For controller classes, it just works, i.e. I added ILogger to the constructor, and save a local reference to the logger, and DI does the rest.

I'm not sure how to implement this for classes that are instantiated by the controller though. For instance:

```
public class MyController: ControllerBase
{
     private readonly ILogger<MyController> _logger;
     public MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger) ( _logger = logger; }

     public bool DoWork() 
    {
         MyWorker w = new MyWorker(???); 
         w.DoSomething();
    }
}

public class MyWorker
{
     private readonly ILogger<MyWorker> _logger;
     public MyWorker(ILogger<MyWorker> logger) 
     {
          _logger = logger;
     }

     public void DoSomething()
     {
          _logger.Debug("DoSomething");
     }

}
```

What is this code supposed to look like when instantiating the MyWorker so it will work with DI?

Comment: As long as the `MyWorker` is registered as part of the services container (i.e. `services.AddScoped<MyWorker>();`), constructor injection will work there too. Unless you are not using the standard DI container .NET/ASP.NET core provides you with (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Follow up: it would then also be necessary to not manually instantiate `MyWorker` in `MyController`, but have it injected as a dependency too (which should automatically be resolved once it's registered in the services container)

Comment: "I'm not sure how to implement this for classes that are instantiated by the controller though" -> you never instantiate classes other than models/entities. Services are always injected by constructor injection

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - How would you change the code so you wouldnt have to instantiate MyWorker via new?

Comment: Add a `public interface IMyWorker { void DoSomething(); }` and implement it in `MyWorker`, then add it to dependency injection and do `private readonly IMyWorker _myWorker; public MyController(IMyWorker myWorker) { _myWorker = myWorker; }` -> basically the same with all services that use/are part of dependency injection